# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion with NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm defining my array in a header with this code: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *editContents;`

The values in the NSArray are set with this code:

```
self.editContents = @[
                      @[@-1,@-1],
                      @[@0,@80],
                      @[@0,@500],
                      @[@-1,@-1],
                      @[@-1,@-1],
                      @[@-1,@-1],
                      @[@-1,@-1],
                      @[@-1,@-1],
                      @[@-1,@-1],
                      @[@-1,@-1],
                      @[@-1,@-1]
                      ];
```

I'm doing some weird stuff with a TableView and TableViewCells to set some values.

However, what the problem boils down to is this code in an IBOutlet:

```
self.superController.editContents[self.index.section][self.index.row] = [self.sortInput.text intValue];
```

Comment: `@-1` is a `NSNumber` litteral so your array is a two-dimensional array of `NSNumber`s. `intValue` is a message that returns an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `NSArray` so you cannot change the values of `NSArray`.Use `NSMutableArray`.But for your code you need to convert it to `NSNumber`.

```
self.superController.editContents[self.index.section][self.index.row] = @([self.sortInput.text intValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.superController.editContents[self.index.section][self.index.row] = @([self.sortInput.text intValue]);
```

However, this won't work because the individual arrays inside of `editContents` are `NSArray`s not `NSMutableArray`s, so they are read-only. Do this:

@[ [@[@-1, @-1] mutableCopy] ]

Tedious, I know. But I see no other way.